# libwebsockets fail to recive or send data correctly to hitbox.tv's websocket

Tags: sockets, websocket

Hello andy well I've been struggling with a slight issue of how should i go about handling web socket connections using libwebsocket. So far it has proved frustrating as it looks like the data is being sent but its not or nto being sent the way they want it and dropped.

So far all the program i made does is connect and ping back and forth and tried so send a json file to their web socket on their server. the issue i am having is do i have everything setup right to be a client and how will i know if i am sending the data correctly or just plain i did something wrong i have no idea. If you could help me that would be great. here is the code in which i am having issues with currently been trying to figure out the issue for over a week now.....

i have changed it several time to try and figure out whats wrong..

http://pastebin.com/jdHbicUi
i have the code pasted in pastebin so its easier for you to view. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was pretty easy for those who have trouble too. The issue is the data being sent needs to be properly buffered on both ends.

```
struct per_session_data {
    unsigned char buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + 4096 +
        LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING];
    unsigned int len;
};

pss->len = sprintf((char *)&pss->buf[
                    LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], "%s", data);
                n = libwebsocket_write(wsi, &pss->buf[
                    LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], pss->len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
```

This will fix any issue with sending the data.